# Docker For Windows kills my network on Windows 10 Bootcamp

Tags: windows, networking, docker, bootcamp

Running Windows 10 Pro in bootcamp on my Mac.  When I install Docker for Windows, the system reboots after enabling HyperV and when it comes back, my network adapters are dead.  Any solutions for this?  I'm not a Windows guy, and not very familiar with how the network drivers work.  They all appear to be set up correctly, but the main Windows driver just wont fire up.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, you can use the alternative approach of:

- not enabling the Hyper-V feature
- add a VirtualBox for Windows on that Windows 10 pro (in Mac bootcamp)

See if you can create containers with the `-d virtualbox` driver instead of relying on Hyper-V.

Comment: Well, I don't need testing... I need it to work, both Docker and my computer. I can use the docker toolbox approach, but that's not really the point.